# How to add line breaks in vs code terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I Have a problem that, my vs code terminal does not have the line break after the output
please tell how to add the line break after the output
(1st image is my output and 2nd image is the expected output)

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: Does your code explicitly have a new line character?

Comment: @im_baby , Actually that is a cpp program, the 1st image contains no `\n` in the program but in the second image i added a `\n` and run the output to describe the actual problem (The problem is the terminal doesn't go to next line whenever a program executed)

Comment: Is this behavior for every program or just yours? In the latter case it could be the intended behavior.

Comment: @im_baby , yes this happens everytime, any ways to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in settings.json when using c++

".cpp":"echo -e",

Answer (score -1):

Open VS Code, go to settings > extentions > Run code configuration open settings.json ( you must have code runner extention installed for this), you must have vscode settings json,
then white `code-runner.executorMap` on newline inside brackets, you must have something like this[image]

then whatever language you code, add on the end of the String

```
"; echo -e"
```

so you must have something like this, for example I code on java
the result is this
[image]

Comment: I followed the process as specified above but it shows the following error, `Write-Output : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'e' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -ErrorAction -ErrorVariable.`

Comment: I dont know, it works on my here, take a look 

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJpsY.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C44nj.png)
and yeah, there is a button to run the code on top right (under window close button)
you must use it or just Ctrl + Alt + N

Comment: i checked all, but it does not work, any other ways to fix it

Comment: May i know the version of PowerShell you are using ?

Comment: Im using ubuntu bash, it must work on cmd and git bash